# Searching in the NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I'm implementing a `UISearchBar` and `SearchDisplayController` to filter the `NSArray` that I parsed from HTML. The data in my array is like in the following format.

```
`"<Book:twRxQxBihF> {\n    bookAuthor = Testing;\n    bookTitle = \"IOS Development\";\n}",
"<Book:kxUTu3rcX5> {\n    bookAuthor = Testing;\n    bookTitle = \"Android Development\";\n}",
.....`
```

My project is about the mobile library and I want to filter the book by Author or Title

As of now I have the NSArray called parseResults to store the data that I parsed and another `NSArray` `filteredResults` to store the final result. I'm pretty new to IOS development and I'm pretty confused with the searching with the scope.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`indexOfObjectPassingTest:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectPassingTest%3a)

```
NSString *search = @"IOS Development";
NSUInteger index = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:
    ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [(NSString*)obj rangeOfString:search].location != NSNotFound;
    }];
```

Example adapted from: [being a blockhead](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2010/06/20/being-a-blockhead/).